# How can we get the view url and download url from amazon s3 bucket?

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3

Uploaded file with two methods.
**Method 1**. file is MultipartFile type

```
InputStream input =file.getInputStream();
   ObjectMetadata metadata=new ObjectMetadata();
   metadata.setContentLength(file.getSize());
   amazon.putObject(bucketName, fileName,input,metadata);
```

**Method 2**. fileObj is of file type

```
amazon.putObject(bucketName, fileName,fileObj);
```

Output:- `String url =  amazon.getUrl(bucketName, fileName).toExternalForm();`

**Method 1:**- If I hit the url, it gets downloaded

**Method 2:**- If I hit the url, it can view from the browser.

**How do I achieve both view and download from any one method?**
Also which is more convenient and effective.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an object is uploaded to Amazon S3 with `Content-Type` metadata, the browser can understand its format and display it (if it knows how).

It would appear that this happens automatically with your Method 2, but boto3 is unable to detect the Content-Type when using Method 1. You would need to add this metadata yourself to produce the same result as Method 2.

To control what is viewed and downloaded, do it in your HTML:

```html
<a href="...">View object</a>
<a href="..." download>Download object</a>
```

Comment: Added the Content-Type. Now i can view the document. But not able to download. I have added this href and download attribute . It's not working. Any specific reason?

Comment: No idea! [HTML a download Attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp)

Comment: No Problem. I Appreciate your help.

Comment: I wanted to ask which is better putObject method?